# Android HttpsURLConnection Authentication

Tags: android

I'm relatively new to java and have been trying to get the source of a webpage after logging in (website is https://stem7.maxnet.co.nz/ispcentre/home.php)

The code I'm using is me trying to expand upon a tutorial. (possibly too far) 
The code below returns the source of the login page and stops there.

```
    private String getSource(URL url) throws IOException {
        HttpsURLConnection spoof = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        String basicAuth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString("username:password".getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);

        spoof.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);

        spoof.setRequestMethod("POST");
        spoof.setUseCaches(false);
        spoof.setDoInput(true);
        spoof.setDoOutput(true);
        spoof.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.0; H010818)");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                spoof.getInputStream()));

        String strLine = "";
        while ((strLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(strLine);
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Even a point in the right direction. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

That page uses form authentication which means when you login, the backend expects the request to contain 2 parameters , one for the username, and one for the password, but your code is using basic authentication which fails everytime, that is why you keep getting the source for the login page (the server cannot authenticate you so it redirects the client back to the login page, hence the HTML source for the login page is returned to you. So you could try doing this

```
connection.setRequestProperty("username", "username");
connection.setRequestProperty("password", "password");
```

Comment: That makes sense. I've used form authentication in c# .net but not java. I tried using your suggestion but get the same result. I added: spoof.setRequestProperty("username","myusername"); and the same for password

Comment: Those `setRequestProperty` calls only set the request headers, so you just need to send your username and password in the request body somehow

Comment: Would this be a good place to start?
 [http://www.peej.co.uk/articles/http-auth-with-html-forms.html](http://www.peej.co.uk/articles/http-auth-with-html-forms.html)

Comment: I am following [https://www.example-code.com/android/http_formAuthentication.asp](https://www.example-code.com/android/http_formAuthentication.asp) will let you know how I get on

Comment: Read the HTTP Authentication section to see how to perform authentication https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: I read the Http authentication section and added in the  Authenticator.setDefault part. Now the app just crashes.

Comment: can you edit your question with the new code, and the strack trace?